# Output a list in cloud formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a parameter:

```
  ClusterSubnets:
    Description: Subnets where cluster will reside.
                Typically private.  Use mutiples, each in a different AZ for HA.
    ConstraintDescription: comma separated list of valid Subnet IDs
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

I'm trying to output this:

```
  ClusterSubnets:
    Description: Subnets used by cluster
    Value: !Ref ClusterSubnets
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ClusterSubnets"
```

But I get this error: Template format error: The Value field of every Outputs member must evaluate to a String.

How can I export a list?

Comment: I think I was once able to get this to work by outputting a string of identifiers separated by commas. So maybe Fn::Join the list with `","`.

Answer (score 22):

You need to join the elements of the list into a string. Try something like this:

```
ClusterSubnets:
    Description: Subnets used by cluster
    Value: !Join
        - ','
        - !Ref ClusterSubnets
    Export:
        Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ClusterSubnets"
```

Here is the relevant [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html).